# How to write multiple variables inside a multiple-line string variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple script to be able to print every fonts to a css `@font-face`

So for every fonts inside a specific directory it should print:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "fontName1", sans-serif;
  src: url("http://localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/fonts/fontName1.ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "fontName2", sans-serif;
  src: url("http://localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/fonts/fontName2.ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

etc...

Now, this is what I tried:

```py
import glob

fontFiles = []

for file in glob.glob("*.ttf"):
    cssRule = """
        @font-face {
            font-family: "{fontName}", sans-serif;
            src: url("http://localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/fonts/{fontFile}");
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    """.format(fontName=file[:-4], fontFile=file)
    print(cssRule)
```

I get the following error when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last File ".\script.py", line 6, in <cssRule = KeyError: '\n            font-family'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Is this because of the `format` inside my python script? What is the best way to write multiple variables inside a multiple-line string variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Enclose in double brace's, this is to espace brace character inside string literal,* [string_formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
for file in glob.glob("*.ttf"):
    cssRule = """
        @font-face {{
            font-family: "{fontName}", sans-serif;
            src: url("http://localhost/wp-content/themes/theme/fonts/{fontFile}");
            font-weight: normal;
        }}
    """.format(fontName=file[:-4], fontFile=file)
    print(cssRule)
```